# Did all Meta sites just encounter a server error?

Tags: bug, 500-server-error

I tried to visit Meta SO and Meta SE in the past five minutes or so, but they both threw an ASPX error:

[image: ASPX error page]

The URL scheme was the following:

`https://meta.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=<path of page>`

Was this the case for all Meta pages? (Stack Overflow didn't seem to have a problem though.)

Comment: Confirmed; lasted less than three minutes for me.

Comment: a real coincidental gem for you - the URL of the request that we picked out of the explosion log (although the error has nothing to do with the specific page) was: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336892/how-to-answer-similar-questions-relating-to-a-service-outage

Comment: Y'all just need to use the app. ;)

Comment: @MarcGravell This is *way* too awesome.

Comment: @Catija too boring, the web is where all the cool things are happening! ;)

Comment: I love how the error page had an error. :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes! Yes they did! Thanks for noticing.

Something went odd in the build. We're looking at what. It worked on the dev staging server, but not on meta which we use as the prod staging server as a final smoke test. This time, [something went terribly wrong](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t3otBjVZzT0).

We're looking into what.

Comment: This answer sounds way too excited ...

Comment: @rene it's always exciting to break things. Did you skip childhood? ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm pretty sure I'm in the middle of that ...

Comment: And it was down for a short while again ...

Comment: or 'Testing In Production'.

Comment: At least ruSO.meta continued to work. I didn’t see error on it yesterday.

Comment: @alexolut we were down for literally a few (low, single digits) minutes; you probably just missed it

Comment: maybe, but [I saw an error for MSE & MSO](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41429462#41429462) while ruSO.meta was alive.

Comment: @alexolut I take it back - you're right - our staging platform is limited to meta.se and possibly meta.so - other metas run through the main multi-tenant tier